# Sending email via Google SMTP

Tags: delphi, indy10

I am using this code to send emails via GMail (encrypted SMTP).

```
pocedure TForm5.SendEmail(const Recipients: string; const Subject: string; const Body: string);
var
  Email: TIdMessage;
  SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  Email := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

  try
    SSLHandler.MaxLineAction := maException;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    SMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
    SMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    SMTP.Port := 587;
    SMTP.Username := 'test1@gmail.com';
    SMTP.Password := '**********';
    SMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

    Email.From.Address := 'test1@gmail.com';
    Email.Recipients.EmailAddresses := Recipients;
    Email.Subject := Subject;
    Email.Body.Text := Body;

    SMTP.Connect;
    if SMTP.Connected then
     begin
      SMTP.Send(Email);
      SMTP.Disconnect;
     end;

  finally
    Email.Free;
    SSLHandler.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The code is working from outside of Delphi IDE, but if ran from inside of the IDE it gives me an AV:

> {Project Tester.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message
>   'access violation at 0x7672bce7: read of address 0x675919d1'}

I have also tried to change SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method, but with the same result.

**The Call Stack**

I don't know how I forgot to mention the strage thing about the AV: The AV in not in the code above. If I press 'Break' it shows the ASM window. The program stops in kernel32.IsBadReadPtr.

```
kernel32.IsBadReadPtr:
769CBCAB 6A0C             push $0c
769CBCAD 6818BD9C76       push $769cbd18
769CBCB2 E8410F0100       call $769dcbf8
769CBCB7 A19460A576       mov eax,[$76a56094]
769CBCBC 8BB02C010000     mov esi,[eax+$0000012c]
769CBCC2 8B450C           mov eax,[ebp+$0c]
769CBCC5 85C0             test eax,eax
769CBCC7 743F             jz $769cbd08
769CBCC9 8B4D08           mov ecx,[ebp+$08]
769CBCCC 85C9             test ecx,ecx
769CBCCE 0F8437BC0200     jz $769f790b
769CBCD4 8D4401FF         lea eax,[ecx+eax-$01]
769CBCD8 89450C           mov [ebp+$0c],eax
769CBCDB 3BC1             cmp eax,ecx
769CBCDD 0F8228BC0200     jb $769f790b
769CBCE3 8365FC00         and dword ptr [ebp-$04],$00
769CBCE7 8A01             mov al,[ecx]         <------------ HERE
769CBCE9 8D56FF           lea edx,[esi-$01]
769CBCEC F7D2             not edx
769CBCEE 8BC2             mov eax,edx
769CBCF0 23C1             and eax,ecx
769CBCF2 8945E4           mov [ebp-$1c],eax
769CBCF5 21550C           and [ebp+$0c],edx
769CBCF8 3B450C           cmp eax,[ebp+$0c]
769CBCFB 0F85FBBB0200     jnz $769f78fc
...
```

The Call Stack is:

- Libeay.DLL,
- Cpruptsp.dll,
- LoadLibraryEXA,
- OnlineArmor.DLL,
- IsBadReadPtr.DLL

OnlineArmor is my firewall!!!!! I don't want to blame it so quickly... but is it possible it is the root if this AV?

I am using:
  this SSL DLL: http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/openssl-0.9.8r-i386-win32-rev2.zip
  Delphi XE
  Indy 10

Comment: On which line is the AV occurring?

Comment: You have `SMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;` but no `SMTP.IOHandler := nil;`. And please indicate WHERE the AV happens (use debug DCUs to see if it is in Indy or somewhere else).

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers: `SMTP.IOHandler := nil` is not needed. `TIdSMTP` uses `FreeNotification()` (like a good component should) to detect if the `TIdIOHandler` object is freed before the `TIdSMTP` object is freed so it can set `IOHandler := nil` automatically.

Comment: @Alter, since the AV only happens in the IDE, please show the debugger's Call Stack that is leading up to the AV.

Comment: The debugger shows you where the exception occurs. What line is it indicating? What's the call stack (View->Debug Windows->Call Stack) at that point?

Comment: @all - I put updates about the CallStack in my original post!

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!! Online Armor won't uninstall!!!!!

Comment: I (hope I) managed to uninstall all bits of Online Armor. Guess what! The code also works from Delphi now!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by uninstalling all bits of Online Armor. The code also works from Delphi now! Lesson not learned! Few years ago I had a similar problem with Kaspersky.

Thank you all for your suggestions. My mind was set on the fulgan DLL. It would have never crossed my mind to uninstall the firewall!